# Can I get 16VAC by combining 8 and 24?

Tags: voltage, ac

I got a doorbell for christmas and it needs 16VAC. I've been looking several places, the transformers that are fixed are fixed at 8 or 12V.

But I came across this one: https://www.kanlux.com/storage/products/techniczna/en/23260.pdf

I live in europe and have 230VAC from the wall :-)

It has output for 0-24VAC. Since I need 16VAC for my doorbell, I can use one wire from 8VAC and 24VAC on the input side to get 16VAC? The 8VAC will pull it down and even it on 16VAC?

Besides, the doorbell I got was the [Ubiquiti G4 Doorbell](https://store.ui.com/collections/unifi-protect-cameras/products/uvc-g4-doorbell), image of the backside:

[image]

So to give it 16VAC I put on wire from 8VAC to one of the terminals and 24VAC to the other?

Added a overview over the circuit that I need to make:

[image]

I dont know what (b) is, but it will make the chime... chime when clicking the button on the doorbell

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the product's datasheet says "16–24V supply", and the question states it's possible to get a 24V supply (it's *very* possible), so there's really no problem to be solved here.

Comment: Hello @MarcusMüller, the case is that this runs in circuit with a chime that needs 16VAC. Ubiquiti has provided another "thing" that I need to install between the doorbell and chime to get it to work. But the chime needs 16. The doorbell operates at 16-24VAC so again; I dont need it to run on 24VAC but 16. Is that possible by taking one wire from 8VAC and another from 24VAC from the transformer? In order to get 16VAC in the circuit that powers both the doorbell and chime

Comment: link to the chime's datasheet? This sounds very unlikely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBXrFl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transformer has no idea about polarity and since it is fully isolated (between primary and secondary) you can call any (one) terminal 0 V and reference from there.

You can obtain 16 V between the terminals marked 8 and 24.

Comment: A "yes" then! Thanks!

Comment: note that the transformer you've found is spec'ed to supply 8 VA, but your doorbell's power consumption is up to 12 VA, and then there's the chime which needs power as well. Reichelt (and basically all large home improvement store web sites) offer established electrical installation company's doorbell transformers with ratings more in the range of 16 to 30 VA, I'd look for these.